# Camel with XA, execute a route or process only after all retries exhausted

Tags: exception, apache-camel, jms, xa

I would like to know if there is a way to tell camel to execute either/preferably a route or some processing that allows me to send to a route only once all the retries are exhausted. I need to be able to send out alerts when things fail but I dont want to send out 5 alerts just because a route retries 5 times and fails.

thanks
Paul

Comment: Share more details about application server, JMS provider and if you can, some example of route. We need to know, if is redelivery handled by Camel or JMS broker.

Comment: apologies, yes that would be helpful! The application is running stand alone using Atomikos as an XA manager. The JMS environment is IBM MQ based... The redelivery as I understand things has to be managed by the JMS provider on XA transactions to ensure the transaction is correctly managed (but if that isnt the case I stand corrected)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ErrorHandler configured with a RedeliveryPolicy. The way it works is that you refer to the ErrorHandler in either your route or your CamelContext. If you use the Dead Letter Channel you can retry, say, five times and then send the message to a different route which stores the message in a JMS queue.

```
<bean id="redeliveryPolicyConfig" class="org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryPolicy">
    <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="5"/>
</bean>  

<bean id="errorHandler" class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder">
   <property name="deadLetterUri" value="direct:myErrorRoute"/>
   <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicyConfig"/>
</bean>

<camelContext errorHandlerRef="errorHandler">
    ...
</camelContext>
```

The above example would retry all routes in the context five times before sending the message to the `direct:myErrorRoute` route where you could, for instance, log the failed message along with the exception and stack trace and/or send it to a DeadLetterQueue.

Comment: as I understand things, the redelivery on XA routes is manged by the JMS provider, I am not sure this approach works for the XA scenario? I suspect my only option realistically is to have an OnCompletion block that only reacts after a prescribed number of retries, it just means I have to know the number of retries defind on the queue and hard code the value in the onCompletion filter which isnt ideal but it would work